# Angular count total items in array without slowing things down

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

Currently I am checking `checkDevice(obj)` to see if a value is present or not... What I also need, separately is to get the count. How many times does **Device** appear in the `Array`.

**component.ts**

```
  public checkDevice(obj) {
    if (obj == null || obj == '' || obj == '-1') {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="float-left" *ngIf="checkDevice(obj.device_token) == true">
   <i class="fa fa-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Edit **php script that does the db query**

```
$users = array();
if ($results = $dbh->runQuery($sql)) {

  foreach ($results as $key=>$row){
    $users[$row['user_id']][] = array('user_id'=>$row['user_id'],
      'user_token' => $row['utoken'],
      'device_token' => $row['device'],
      'group_name' => $row['group_name']);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is you obj looks like? and where you want to show the device count?

Comment: You should not data-bind functions in the template.

Comment: Which `Array` are you referring to?

Comment: @Ntwobike I want the device count to be right after the icon </i> tag.

Comment: @lealceldeiro I updated and posted the Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test if the object property exists, then you should go with something like this:

```
<div class="float-left" *ngIf="obj.device_token">
  <i class="fa fa-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

If you want to get the occurrence of the device object in an array, then try this solution:

```
getDeviceOccurrence(deviceArray: Array<object>, device: object): number {
  return deviceArray.reduce((accumulator: number, currentValue: object) => {
    if (_.isEqual(currentValue, device)) {
      return accumulator = accumulator + 1;
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, 0);
}
```

**Notes for the proposed solution:**

- For comparing objects it is easier to import [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and use its [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual) function.
- The function takes two parameter. The first one is the array which holds devices. The second is the device. The function will return a number which is the occurrence of the device object in the array.
- This solution uses [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

**Usage in template:**

```
<span>{{ getDeviceOccurrence(devices, device) }}</span>
```

Comment: I should be able to call `accumulator` like this `{{accumulator}}` in the component.html?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also write this code.

```
<div class="float-left" *ngIf="obj.device_toke">
   <i class="fa fa-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you don't use functions to data-bind in your HTML, this can have performance issues, since your functions it will be called to check everytime.

I think that you already have the array with your devices and you are iterating in a **ngFor**.

The steps that I recommend you are:

- Create an purgued array where you clean all the devices with the token en null or empty
- Use that array to bind it to your **ngFor** (You will be sure that the token is loaded)

Doing that you resolve two thing:

- The performance issue you have binding a function to the ***ngIf**
- You will resolve the count issue you have, since you will have a new array with all the items that has a token.